# CSS Using Top Position Negative figures ? Is this normal or a hack?

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of Div's with background images and the top one has a curve.

I need to just the bottom one with the top so I was thinking of using:

```
top: -39px;
width: 260px;
```

Is this use ok or is this considered a hack ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely fine and normal and common and not a hack to use negative values.